# Not able to read Config from custom exception filter in controller attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception

Trying to read configuration from custom exception filter into controller attribute i have attached screenshots for reference.

- My controller

[image: controller]

- My ExceptionFilter

[image: apiexceptionfilter]

- Startup.cs

[image: startup.cs]

**error is how to read it into controller attribute**

[image]

Comment: What's the error then?

Comment: Not able to put exception filter to a controller as attribute because it is parameterized constructor is there any way to use it??

Comment: Could you please add the actual error to your question please

Comment: Build the solution and paste the error you get

Comment: Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'ApiExceptionFilter.ApiExceptionFilter(IConfiguration)' ECP.AdminUI D:\bitbucket\ecp-identityadminui\src\ECP.AdminPanelUI\ECP.AdminUI\Controllers\ApplicationController.cs 20 Active